# Slow MySQL query when using LIKE operation on large table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I have a fairly large table (~ 6 GB) and I have performance problems on this query:

```
          SELECT f.*,
          TIME_FORMAT(f.scheme, '%H:%i') as scheme,
          TIME_FORMAT(f.actual, '%H:%i') as actual,
          DATE_FORMAT(f.flight_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as flight_date_formatted,
          a.iata
          FROM flights_database f
          LEFT JOIN airports a ON f.airport = a.airportNameClean
          WHERE f.flight_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
          AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
          AND (f.flight_number LIKE 'New York%' OR f.airport LIKE 'New York%' OR f.airline LIKE 'New York%')
          ORDER by f.flight_date DESC, f.flight_scheme DESC
          LIMIT 50"
```

I've used `EXPLAIN` and identified these underlying problems

- The usage of multiple LIKE's and OR let's it use a range (using WHERE) of records and appears to make it slow
- f.flight_scheme DESC, when this is added filesort is used. When removed, filesort is not used.

I have an index on `flight_date, flight_number, airport, airline, scheme` and it reports to use it.
But this query can still take ~30 seconds which off course is too much.

What probably would help is using some kind of subquery to replace the OR part. But how can I determine what type of search query (e.g. which column) I actually need to search on after running the subquery.

Ideas and tips appreciated.

Comment: instead of LIKE, get all possible filght_number going to newyork based on location id or some thing and do a JOIN, similar thing for other columns.

Comment: If you can't use a system that FK references cities and use either an indexed lookup or a direct FK value, then perhaps a structure akin to `'New York' IN (LEFT(f.flight_number,8), LEFT(f.airport,8), LEFT(f.airline,8))` would work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your current index isn't optimal for the query mainly because of the 'or' expression. You should create 3 indexes.

(flight_number, flight_date, schema)

(airport, flight_date, schema)

(airline, flight_date, schema)

Then change the query to use the three indexes. You could also play with it a bit and maybe prune each sub query by adding an order by and limit to 50 as well.

```
select flight.*,
    TIME_FORMAT(flight.scheme, '%H:%i') as scheme,
    TIME_FORMAT(flight.actual, '%H:%i') as actual,
    DATE_FORMAT(flight.flight_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as flight_date_formatted,
    a.iata
from (
    select *
    from (
        select f.Id,
            f.flight_date,
            f.schema
        from flights_database f
        where f.flight_date between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
            and f.flight_number like 'New York%'
        order by f.flight_date desc,
            f.schema desc limit 50

        union

        select f.Id,
            f.flight_date,
            f.schema
        from flights_database f
        where f.flight_date between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
            and f.airline like 'New York%'
        order by f.flight_date desc,
            f.schema desc limit 50

        union

        select f.Id,
            f.flight_date,
            f.schema
        from flights_database f
        where f.flight_date between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
            and f.airport like 'New York%'
        order by f.flight_date desc,
            f.schema desc limit 50
        ) f1
    order by f1.flight_date desc,
        f.schema desc limit 50
    ) f2
inner join flights_database flight on f2.Id = flight.Id
left join airports a on flight.airport = a.airportNameClean;
```

Currently your or statement will expand to:
[flight_date, flight_number], [flight_date, airline], [flight_date, airport]

So when the optimizer looks at your index it will match 
[flight_date, flight_number] to your current index [flight_date, flight_number, airport, airline, scheme] (notice how they start off the same), but when it encounters [flight_date, airline] there isn't an index to match this expression. So the optimizer would determine it would need to do a index scan or a table scan. Then it would encounter [flight_date, airport] again it will determine this to require a index scan or a table scan.

With the three new indexes and the new query it would match the three indexes to the three criteria and determine each would require an index seek (hopefully). Then we include 'scheme' to save the row lookup by id for all the rows matching the criteria.

Comment: Interesting approach. Due to the table size will take a while before the indexes are alter. Will report back. Thanks.

Comment: OK, index generation was faster than I expected. I added the suggested indexes, odd thing is when I run just one of the subquery's (e.g. for airport) the index used is the index on just the airport column, and not the new index. Nontheless query speed is fine when ORDER BY clause is omitted. When it is added again, it resorts to use filesort again and makes it slow :(

Comment: That is odd... Can you try hinting the index? flights_database f use index (composite_index_name).

Comment: Yes, see this screenshot without hinting and with hinting. But the filesort maybe is not due to that part of the query? Your complete query runs in less than 2 seconds which is impressive by itself anyway. http://cl.ly/image/1s1D282E1C1x (without hinting) http://cl.ly/image/1k0M0D1H3g3Y (with hinting)

Comment: Something else you could try is changing the index order. (airline, flight_date, schema)

Comment: Oh, I see the issue now, I'll update the query in a bit here.

Comment: I believe each sub query was returning to many rows, 200k each. So we limit those and that should fix it up. If there is still an issue lets move this discussion to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63613/discussion-between-edwardmp-and-will).