# Mysql multiple LIKE with "AND"

Tags: php, mysql

I have problems about `LIKE` operator. I create query whose is searching with like something for example, I search Street 34:

```
WHERE address LIKE '%Street%' AND address LIKE '%34%'
```

Problem is that if I'm writing too long address MySQL query slows freaking down. Is there possible any faster solution? I know there is operators `REGEXP` or `IN` but they search using `OR` but I need search BY `AND`.

ps: Why I'm writing multiple `LIKE`? Its because Some may message not "Street 34" but "34 Street".

Comment: is your table properly indexed?

Comment: I indexed in BTREE the same, i indexed FULLTEXT then its search only by words but in my case it would be better it search after each letter. Minimal letters starts from 3

Comment: If the LIKE operand starts with a **%** MySql cant use a INDEX. so your query is a **FULL TABLE SCAN** and see what @Romans Leonovs has written

Comment: it might also depend on what your SELECT looks like

Comment: SELECT address FROM table WHERE address LIKE '%street%' AND address LIKE '%34%'

Comment: indexes cant be used on like if the first character is a wild-card `'%street%'` = no index `'street%'` = index used

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26492836/ --- http://stackoverflow.com/q/12745681/ --- http://stackoverflow.com/q/6695746/ and keep searching for "query slows down when using LIKE mysql".

Comment: The think is that if i use one or two LIKE its find fast but WHEN im using 5 to 7 LIKE then query gets very slow. Maybe there is any mysql function LIKE REGEXP but whose search with AND not OR

Answer (score 0):

Add a search table in which you have an id and varchar field.

Put every unique individual word in it.

Make a linking table that links words to their adresses.

Table adresses

```
Id address
1  34 bakersfield
2  steve irwing street 34
```

Table words

```
  Id  word
  1  34
  2  bakersfield
  3  steve
  4  Irwing
  5  Street
```

Linking table

```
   Street_id  word_id
   1.              1
   1.              2
   2.              3
   2.              4
   2.              5
   2.              1
```

Then all you have to do is a where and joins.

You can also use where in queries.

An alternative can also be to enable full text indexing which does the same(but better), but behind the screens.

Answer (score 0):

The `LIKE "%term%"` cannot benefit from an index, and this means you are subjecting your database to a full table scan. As you've noticed this is quite slow.

Have you taken a look at MySQL full-text searching? This would speed things up quite considerably if you're using the myisam engine: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html.

Comment: Yes i already check out fulltext indexing. Its works faster but in the same its address search. I have databse with many of address and my point is make a system where user can search address. About fulltext index problem is client may not know fully some address name for example he's write city name Kars but he dont know how to end it. and there many variables like hes gonna write street street nr and city but database string saves it as city street streen nr. Im trying to make search like google taking smt above